# i am trying to create a activity where user can select pdf and audio file and upload to the firebase storage if the file size is less then 16mb

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have created an activity where the user can select pdf and audio file from the storage and upload to the firebase storage if the file size is less than 16mb. to check the file size I have created a method where filesize is been compared whether the file size is less than 16mb. this activity should upload the file but whenever I select any file an error occurs says

> error:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=438, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/35
>   flg=0x1 }} to activity
>   {com.nanb.Alpha/com.nanb.Alpha.personalchat.personalChat}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException.

I have searched for the solution and found that the file isn't selected but didn't get any solution tor to remove the error.

the code is given below that I have used:

```
 audio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checker = "audio";
            Intent audioIntent = new Intent();
            audioIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            audioIntent.setType("audio/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(audioIntent,"Select Audio"),438);
        }
    });
    pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checker = "pdf";
            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent();
            pdfIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            pdfIntent.setType("application/pdf");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pdfIntent,"Select pdf file"),438);
        }
    });
```

I have also tried to put

```
     Intent audioIntent = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(audioIntent, "Select Audio"), AUDIO_REQUEST);
```

still get the same error. Rest all the codes are as follows:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 438 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null && data.getData()!=null){
        imagefile = data.getData();
        String filePath = this.getRealPathFromURI(imagefile);
        Long Filelength = this.getfilesize(filePath);
        if(checckfilesize(Filelength).equals("ok")) {
         if (checker.equals("pdf")) {
               pdfFilemessage(filePath);
            }else{
               String fileName = this.getfilename(filePath);
                audiofilemessage(filePath,fileName);
         }
       }
      }


       public Long getfilesize(String filepath){
    File filedata = new File(filepath);
    Long fileLength = filedata.length();
    fileLength = fileLength/1024;
    return fileLength;
}
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
    };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
    //        Toast.makeText(personalChat.this, 
   Long.toString(cursor.getLong(sizeIndex)),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
public String checckfilesize(Long Filelength){
    String checkstate;
    if(Filelength < 16000 ){
        checkstate = "ok";
    }else{
        checkstate = "file large than 16mb.";
    }
    return checkstate;
}
private String getfilename(String filepath){
    File file = new File(filepath);
    String filename = file.getName();
    return filename;
}
```

retrieve temp file

```
  private void reciverpdftempImage(Uri imagefile, String msgpushId) {
    int pageNumber = 0;
    PdfiumCore pdfiumCore = new PdfiumCore(this);
    try {

        ParcelFileDescriptor fd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(imagefile, "r");
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = pdfiumCore.newDocument(fd);
        pdfiumCore.openPage(pdfDocument, pageNumber);
        int width = pdfiumCore.getPageWidthPoint(pdfDocument, pageNumber);
        int height = pdfiumCore.getPageHeightPoint(pdfDocument, pageNumber);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        pdfiumCore.renderPageBitmap(pdfDocument, bmp, pageNumber, 0, 0, width, height);
        saveImage(bmp,msgpushId);
        pdfiumCore.closeDocument(pdfDocument); // important!
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //todo with exception
    }
}
```

upload the audio and pdf file to the firebase

```
   private void audiofilemessage(String vfilePath,final String filename) {
    StorageReference imagereference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Audio");
    final String msgSenderref = "Chats/" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/" + userid;
    final String msgReciverref = "Chats/" + userid + "/" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference usermsgKeyRef = rootref.child("Chats").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(userid).push();
    final String msgPushId = usermsgKeyRef.getKey();
    final StorageReference filePath = imagereference.child(msgPushId+"."+"mp3");
    uploadTask = filePath.putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(vfilePath)));
    String destinationfile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Alpha/Audio/Send/"+msgPushId+".mp3";
    copyFileOrDirectory(vfilePath,destinationfile);
    uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
        @Override
        public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                throw task.getException();
            }
            return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                String myUrl = downloadUri.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),myUrl,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // uploadfiletotheserver(myUrl,filename,checker,msgPushId,msgSenderref,msgReciverref);

            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            loadingBar.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(personalChat.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

private void pdfFilemessage(String vfilePath) {

    StorageReference imagereference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Doc");
    final String msgSenderref = "Chats/" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/" + userid;
    final String msgReciverref = "Chats/" + userid + "/" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference usermsgKeyRef = rootref.child("Chats").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(userid).push();
    final String msgPushId = usermsgKeyRef.getKey();
    reciverpdftempImage(imagefile,msgPushId);
    final StorageReference filePath = imagereference.child(msgPushId+"."+"pdf");
    uploadTask = filePath.putFile(imagefile);
    String destinationfile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Alpha/pdf/Send/"+msgPushId+".pdf";
    copyFileOrDirectory(vfilePath,destinationfile);
    uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
        @Override
        public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                throw task.getException();
            }
            return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                String myUrl = downloadUri.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),myUrl,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //uploadpdfTempfile(myUrl,imagefile,checker,msgPushId,msgSenderref,msgReciverref);
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            loadingBar.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(personalChat.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
private void uploadpdfTempfile(final String myUrl,final Uri imagefile,final String checker, final String msgPushId, final String msgSenderref, final String msgReciverref) {
    StorageReference imagereference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Doc").child("temp");
    Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Alpha/PDF/temp/"+msgPushId+".png"));
    final StorageReference fileuploadpath = imagereference.child(msgPushId+".png");
    uploadTask = fileuploadpath.putFile(file);
    uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
        @Override
        public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                throw task.getException();
            }
            return fileuploadpath.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                String  myfileUrl = downloadUri.toString();
                //Toast.makeText(personalChat.this,myfileUrl,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                uploadpdfdatatotheserver(myUrl,imagefile,checker,msgPushId,msgSenderref,msgReciverref,myfileUrl);

            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(personalChat.this,"Error:"+ e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
private void uploadpdfdatatotheserver(String myUrl, Uri imagefile, String checker, final String msgPushId, final String msgSenderref, final String msgReciverref,final String myfileurl) {


    Map msgpicbody = new HashMap();
    msgpicbody.put("message",myUrl);
    msgpicbody.put("name",imagefile.getLastPathSegment());
    msgpicbody.put("type",checker);
    msgpicbody.put("ffrom",mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    msgpicbody.put("to",userid);
    msgpicbody.put("date", savecurrentDate);
    msgpicbody.put("time",savecurrentTime);
    msgpicbody.put("messageId",msgPushId);
    msgpicbody.put("tempfile",myfileurl);

    Map msgBodyDetail = new HashMap();
    msgBodyDetail.put(msgSenderref + "/" +msgPushId,msgpicbody);
    msgBodyDetail.put(msgReciverref + "/" +msgPushId,msgpicbody);

    rootref.updateChildren(msgBodyDetail).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                loadingBar.dismiss();
                msginput.setText(null);
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }else{
                loadingBar.dismiss();
                msginput.setText(null);
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(personalChat.this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

logcat

```
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=438, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/35 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.nanb.Alpha/com.nanb.Alpha.personalchat.personalChat}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4090)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4133)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1534)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6125)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:262)
    at com.nanb.Alpha.personalchat.personalChat.getfilesize(personalChat.java:813)
    at com.nanb.Alpha.personalchat.personalChat.onActivityResult(personalChat.java:179)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7194)
```

Comment: Dont use code like get real path from uri. Hence you cannot use the File class to determine file size. Thow that all away.

Comment: Instead get a content resolver and query it with the obtained uri for file size. Adapt to modern times. Do it now to be ready for Android 10 and R.

Comment: Did u add permissions for read/ write storage and allow them?